# Constantly reporting data to be added to datagridview from background worker hangs the UI

Tags: c#, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that retrieves data from an external source.
My `BackgroundWorker` then processes the data and updates the original source with modified data.
I report back out of my `BackgroundWorker` to fill a `DataGridView` of what has been processed etc.

if it runs nice and slow then my UI is freed up enough for me to use the cancel button if a problem occurs but if it runs quickly (if the data its processing is minimal) then the UI is kept busy adding rows to the `DataGridView` and I can't use the cancel button in a timely fashion

So... my question is what would be the correct method to constantly update the `DataGridView` whilst still retaining some UI control to press cancel but without slowing the process down further.

Comment: The DGV update has to happen on the UI thread, so all I can suggest is don't update the DGV so often. Maybe only every 500ms.

Comment: ok but if im adding rows and colouring the rows appropriate to whats go on how can i do that without the ui updating?

would i update another dgv that isnt displayed and then every 500ms pass that over to the one i have UI form ?

Comment: No, that would be a bit of a round-about way of doing it. I posted an answer to explain what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're doing all the grid updates at the end, when the BackgroundWorker's `RunWorkerCompleted` event fires. Instead, set BackgroundWorker's WorkerReportsProgress property to true, and have your DoWork method call `ReportProgress` whenever you want to pass some new data to go in the grid.

Comment: No i add each row in the
private void BW_Progress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
   datagridview1.rows.add....
}

The problem is that the background work downloads the data in batches and processes each item in the data and reports back to dgv about whats been processed, if there is a lot of data it does it really quickly and reports so often that the UI is frozen as its updating/adding rows constantly so i cant press stop or cancel

Answer (score 0):

In your backgroundworker's run method, I assume you have something like this:

```
foreach (var result in database.GetAllResults()) {
    bw.ReportProgress(result);
}
```

You could try restricting the code to one update per 500 milliseconds (or whatever number seems to work best), by changing it to something like this:

```
var buffer = new List<Result>();
var lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var result in database.GetAllResults()) {
    buffer.Add(result);
    if (DateTime.Now > lastUpdate.AddMilliseconds(500)) {
        bw.ReportProgress(buffer);
        buffer.Clear();
        lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
if (buffer.Any()) bw.ReportProgress(buffer);
```

And of course, in your progress handler, you now have a `List<Result>` being passed instead of a single `Result`, so you need to add a for-loop there too.

Answer (score -1):

According to MSDN,  [Thread.Sleep(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/d00bd51t%28v=vs.100%29) after each `ReportProgress` should do it:

> Specify zero (0) to indicate that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute.